# Encoding of the actual header value for HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, encoding, httprequest

I'm trying to create a POST request that requires a customer header with a value that contains the Norwegian character ø.

Using PostMan this works just fine, but I get an error response when trying it from my application. The line I use to add the header to the response is this:

```
request.Headers.Add("Customer-Name", "Test Strøm AS");
```

However, when I check the actual request using Fiddler, I see that the header comes out like this:

```
Customer-Name: Hafslund Str�m AS
```

The request from PostMan looks correct.

How can I get the HttpRequestMessage to use the correct encoing for the actual header value?

Comment: Does it decode it accurately at the other end? i.e. does it work?

Comment: Nope, it responds that the customer-name header has to be utf-8. It works when called from PostMan

Comment: @DavidG - I hope that not is the only way to do it. That seems like jumping through A LOT of hoops just to set the Encoding for the header?

Comment: Well if you find a better way, feel free to post an answer!  :)

Comment: I tried this way, and it did not work. After pushing it through `HeaderNameValueEncode` it still gets the same result. And that is not very strange, considering since it does not encode anything higher than char no 127, and ø is higher than that.

Comment: Create a StringContent with UTF8 encoding and add the headers there.

Comment: Gusman - I tried now with the same result in the actual header :(